# Memoryleak when using ICollectionView with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, memory-leaks

So in my application I use an ICollectionView of Products, which is bound to a DataGrid with DataBinding. The Products come from a MS-SQL table and this table is quiet big (~30.000 entries). At certain points I need to reload the table as its contents might have changed.

Whenever I call ReloadProducts() ~30.000 new objects are created. The  previous objects are not freed up and remain in memory for whole the live of the application.

Any idea how I could force a disposal of the old objects?

ViewModel:

```
private ICollectionView _productCollectionView;

public ICollectionView ProductCollectionView 
{
    set { _productCollectionView = value; }
    get
    {
        if (_productCollectionView == null)
        {
            ReloadProducts();
        }
        return _productCollectionView ;
    }
}

public void ReloadProducts()
{
  List<Products> productList = Entities.Products.ToList();
  ProductCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(productList);
  NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCollectionView");
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollectionView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
```

Comment: Where are you notify view about changes in ProductCollectionView ?

Comment: I forgot that line when formatting the code for this question. I added it in my post.

Comment: How do you determine that you have memory leak? Do you use memory profiler? Have you call GC.Collect() manualy? Why you think, that leak exactly in this place?

Comment: Yes, I used a memory profiler. The leak is definitly in this place. Each time ReloadProducts() the memory profiler shows that the amount of new objets in memory matches the amount of entries in the Products table.

Comment: Yup, but are you sure that there are no any part of code which store reference on your previous values of ProductCollectionView ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use collection neither it's view. Binding will connect to the collection's view on itself.

Just use something like this :

```
    private ObservableCollection<Products> _productCollectionView;

    public ObservableCollection<Products> ProductCollectionView 
    {
        set { _productCollectionView = value; }
        get
        {
            if (_productCollectionView == null)
            {
                ReloadProducts();
            }
            return _productCollectionView ;
        }
    }

    public void ReloadProducts()
    {
      ProductCollectionView.Clear();
      ObservableCollection<Products> ProductCollectionView = 
new ObservableCollection<Products>(Entities.Products.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would probably work. However I am forced to use ICollectionView because I need to apply a filter to it.

Comment: try: 
'public void ReloadProducts()
    {
      ProductCollectionView.Clear();
      ProductCollectionView = new CollectionViewSource();
      ProductCollectionView.Source = Entities.Products.ToList();
    }'